# Random blue color on top of keyboard when selecting emoticons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboard, ios7.1

I am getting this blue bar on the top of the default keyboard when emojis are shown. I have no idea where it is coming from and can't get rid of it! I do not have any custom code on the keyboard. I am simply showing the keyboard when a UITextField is tapped.

Some more info:

1. All settings on keyboard are set to default.
2. There are no UIView elements with that color on the view controller.
3. No accessory is added to the keyboard.
4. This only happens on the emoji keyboard. Possibly because it is the only with the page indicator.

Thanks for checking the issue out!

[image: Screenshot of keyboard]

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode? Xcode act weird sometimes for no reason..

Comment: @Ty_ Restarting did not help. Also, this is happening on the actual device (not the simulator).

Comment: Is this a custom keyboard?

Comment: @Ty_ it is the default keyboard. Using iOS 7.

Comment: Try delete and running the app again in you device. Its not your fault its, probably an xcode bug

Comment: @Ty_ Thanks for the suggestions! Tried this but no go. This is happening on multiple devices built with different Xcode / machines.

Comment: What I suggest you do is comment all your code and create a new plain Uitextfield and see if this still happens. You might missed out one line of your code that caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer! I forgot that I had changed the UIPageControl's color globally for a UITabBarController. I had no idea that would affect the default keyboard's UIPageControl's color.

The code that was the culprit:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: You can scope your use of the `UIAppearance` proxy by using `apperanceWhenContainedIn:`.